# Apache Axis: no containing element

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I received the following WSDL from a vendor.  The sample service behind it runs on Microsoft .NET.  I need to create a web service in Java based on this WSDL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
xmlns:tns="http://www.somecompany.com/" 
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
targetNamespace="http://www.somecompany.com/" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.somecompany.com/">
    <s:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd" />
      <s:element name="getInventoryStatus">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DealerCode" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SupplierCode" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PartNumber" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Quantity" type="s:int" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DeliveryLocation" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="getInventoryStatusResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="getInventoryStatusResult">
              <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:element ref="s:schema" />
                  <s:any />
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="getInventoryStatusSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getInventoryStatus" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getInventoryStatusSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getInventoryStatusResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="InventoryInquirySoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="getInventoryStatus">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getInventoryStatusSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getInventoryStatusSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="InventoryInquirySoap" type="tns:InventoryInquirySoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getInventoryStatus">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.somecompany.com/getInventoryStatus" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="InventoryInquiry">
    <wsdl:port name="InventoryInquirySoap" binding="tns:InventoryInquirySoap">
      <soap:address location="http://www.somecompany.com/InventoryInquiry.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I modified the WSDL I received to include the following line so that Eclipse would recognize the WSDL as valid:

```
<s:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd" />  <!--  added for Eclipse-->
```

I've included this WSDL file in a new Dynamic Web Project.  I used the New Web Service wizard to create a new top down web service based on the WSDL.

When I deploy the project to Tomcat and call the web service, Apache Axis reports back the following:

> AXIS error
>
> Sorry, something seems to have gone wrong... here are the details:
>
> Fault - makeTypeElement() was told to create a type
>   "{http://www.somecompany.com/}>>getInventoryStatusResponse>getInventoryStatusResult",
>   with no containing element
>
> AxisFault  faultCode:
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.generalException 
>   faultSubcode:   faultString: makeTypeElement() was told to create a
>   type
>   "{http://www.somecompany.com/}>>getInventoryStatusResponse>getInventoryStatusResult",
>   with no containing element  faultActor:   faultNode:   faultDetail: 
>     {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:HOME-DELL

The demo web service provided by the vendor returns the following:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetInventoryStatusResponse xmlns="http://ctire.aktion.com/">
         <GetInventoryStatusResult>
            <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
               <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                  <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="InventoryStatus">
                           <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                 <xs:element name="InStock" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="EstDeliveryDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="EstDeliveryTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="DeliveryLocation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                           </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                     </xs:choice>
                  </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
               <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                  <InventoryStatus diffgr:id="InventoryStatus1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                     <InStock>36</InStock>
                     <EstDeliveryDate>09/27/2016</EstDeliveryDate>
                     <EstDeliveryTime>12:00 PM</EstDeliveryTime>
                     <DeliveryLocation>883620750</DeliveryLocation>
                  </InventoryStatus>
               </NewDataSet>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
         </GetInventoryStatusResult>
      </GetInventoryStatusResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I think I need to reference a schema for the NewDataSet in the WSDL, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know [soapUI](https://www.soapui.org/)? You can import your WSDL and make some requests against the demo service. Just to check that your infrastructure works properly.

If everything seems to work, try this:
Have Java generate the classes from the WSDL via the "wsimport" command like this:

> %JAVA_HOME%/bin/wsimport -d [RELATIVE_PATH_FOR_GENERATED_CLASSES] -encoding UTF-8 -keep -verbose [RELATIVE_PATH_OF_YOUR_WSDL]

In your code try to use these generated classes and deploy again.

You can get the full documentation of wsimport from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html)

Hope that helps in any way.

Comment: What's the difference between wsimport and using Axis, which is included with Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I know soapUI.  As noted in the question, the issue is that I can't access the service that Axis builds, due to an issue with Axis conversion of the WSDL to Java classes.

Comment: Have you tried to generate the artifacts via wsimport? This tool has served me well more than once. Other tools' outcome - I can't remember which I tried but I think AXIS was one of them - didn't work.

Comment: Maybe this link is useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627240/axis-vs-jax-ws-for-web-service-client

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use JAX-WS, which is a Java Standard. It cooperates easily with JAXB, which is also needed here.

In this case, the server has a dynamic response which includes an schema definition and a free object, but it seems that is an diffgram node (from a Microsoft XSD) and an object instance that complies with the previous XSD definition and some diffgram attributes.

This solution ignores the diffgram node (but not it's contents) because i don't have the appropiate XSD from Microsoft (it's supposed to be in "msdata.xsd from Visual Studio %InstallRoot%\Xml\Schemas directory). It's only a matter of putting the right XSD and following the steps.

Steps to create the service:

- Download http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/cxf/2.7.18/apache-cxf-2.7.18.zip
- In Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> CXF -> Add and then select + apply
- Create a Dynamic Web Project and put the WSDL in src
- Web Services -> Generate Java Skeleton -> Runtime CXF -> Finish
- Put in the schema definition from the sample response in diffgram-v1.xsd
- Generate JAXB classes in a command line with "xjc diffgram-v1.xsd" (from java bin classpath)
- Change GetInventoryStatusResponse.GetInventoryStatusResult adding before class definition "@XmlSeeAlso({NewDataSet.class})" to support returning this object via JABX in the service
- Implement InventoryInquirySoapImpl.getInventoryStatus returning the XSD parsed and an instance of NewDataSet:

  ```
      InventoryStatus ie = new InventoryStatus();
      ie.setDeliveryLocation("del");
      ie.setInStock(36);
      ie.setEstDeliveryDate("09/27/2016");
      ie.setDeliveryLocation("883620750");

      NewDataSet nds = new NewDataSet();
      nds.getInventoryStatus().add(ie);

      GetInventoryStatusResponse.GetInventoryStatusResult _return = new GetInventoryStatusResponse.GetInventoryStatusResult();

      _return.setSchema(parseDiffgramSchema());
      _return.setAny(nds);
      return _return;
  ```
- parseDiffgramSchema can be implemented with JABX:

  ```
  // TODO cache
  URL file = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
          .getResource("diffgram-v1.xsd");

  JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Schema.class);

  Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

  Schema schema = (Schema) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

  return schema;
  ```

  - URL to call: http://localhost:8081/TestJAXWS/services/InventoryInquirySoap

Full example in my GIT https://github.com/sergio-otero/TestJAXWS/tree/master/TestJAXWS

Comment: I'm using Axis to create the web service from the WSDL, not to create a client to invoke the existing service.

Comment: Ok. I have an example returning the "xs:schema" part but not the "diffgram" part. I'll be easier if you can provide msdata.xsd from Visual Studio %InstallRoot%\Xml\Schemas directory

Comment: The actual .NET web service is from a vendor.  I've asked them for that schema.

Comment: Changed solution from generating client to publishing server, but without the full XSD from Microsoft

Comment: I'm going to give you the reward because you definitely made an effort to help me with this.  Unfortunately, I have a rush project to tackle and won't be able to look at this until next week or so.  I'll add comments here in case I get stuck. Thanks!